# Передать в метод класса boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, bind

Пусть есть какой-то класс, которому в некий метод хочу передать объект `boost::bind`:

```
class FOO
{
    void f( /*type???*/ boostbind_, int i_)
    {
         /* ??? вызов boostbind с параметром i_*/
    }
};
```

И есть другой класс, метод которого я хочу передать:

```
class BOO
{
   void b()
   {
        int i=0;
        auto t = boost::bind(&BOO::b2, this, _1, _2, i);
        obj.f(t, i);
   }
   void b2(boost::system::error_code, size_t, int);
   FOO obj;
};
```

Как правильно объявить метод класса, в который передается `boost::bind` и как его потом использовать?

**P.S.** Подразумевается, что класс `FOO` ничего не знает о классе `BOO` (в том числе и об его существовании)

**UPDATE**
Попытка сделать через `boost::function` выдает ошибки компиляции при использовании с `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::async_receive_from(...)`.
Пример кода (для компиляции инициализировать(что занимает много дополнительного кода) сокет не обязательно):

```
class FOO
{
public:
    void f(boost::function<void(boost::system::error_code ec_, size_t size_, int i_)> boostbind_)
    {
        s->async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 2048),
            endPoint,
            boostbind_);
    }
    char buffer[2048];
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endPoint;
    shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> s;
};
class BOO
{
public:
    void b()
    {
        int i = 99;
        obj.f(boost::bind(&BOO::b2, this, _1, _2, i));
    }
    void b2(boost::system::error_code ec_, size_t size_, int i_)
    { 
        std::cout << "\nb2";
    }

    FOO obj;
};

int main()
{
    BOO a;
    a.b();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки компиляции:

> Error 1   error C2338: ReadHandler type requirements not met  c:\libs\boost\boost\asio\basic_datagram_socket.hpp  893 1   Test
>
> Error 2   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments    c:\libs\boost\boost\asio\basic_datagram_socket.hpp  893 1   Test

Comment: Может использовать boost::function ?

Comment: Каким  образом? Можно пример по шаблону в вопросе?

Comment: А для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: @VladD уменьшить связность кода, сделать обертки для однотипных операций(состоящих из нескольких этапов). По хорошему, класс FOO ничего не должен знать о классе BOO

Comment: На тогда boost::function, да. Или обновите версию языка, теперь это std::function.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp341945152) в вашем случае как-то так:

```
void f(boost::function<void(int x)> boostbind_, int i_);
```

Единственные сомнения вызывают ваш вызов `boost::bind`, опять же, судя по [документации к boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu) в конце вам не нужно передавать в `bind` параметр `i`, т.к. для него вы уже передали `placeholders::_2`. Соответственно в `void f()` вы делаете вызов `boostbind_(i_);`

Comment: А, мне не нужно передавать в `f` параметр `i`

Comment: `int x` в `boost::function` я написал исходя из документации, но как оказалось в этом нет необходимости, проверил ваш код [тут](http://ideone.com/VVjuX7), и вы правы, в `boost::bind` не надо передавать аргументы `i` и `_2`.

Comment: Тоже уже разобрался. Надо в шаблоне `boost::function` указать ТОЛЬКО аргументы, для которых выделены `placeholders`.

Comment: ваша функция, которую вы передаете в `async_recieve_from` должна иметь сигнатуру 

    void handler(
        const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
        std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes received.
     ); 
т.е. ваш аргумент `i_` - лишний, вместо него необходимо привязать либо конкретное значние, либо отказаться вовсе.

Comment: Верхний комментарий не могу отредактировать, но вижу, что вы разобрались с проблемой.

Comment: На будущее, вдруг кому понадобится готовое решение, можете вставить в ответ код примера по ссылке: http://pastebin.com/dYQa19Cf ? Ну или хотя бы часть, которая показывает основную часть синтаксиса